# Extracting a value from a string with k='v' pairs in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

so i have the following string:

```
packageinfo="package: name='nl.test.app' versionCode='64' versionName='5.1' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2438415'"
```

...set as a shell variable, to allow the following:

```
echo $packageinfo
```

i want to extract the value in between quotes after name= so i need variable that will contain `nl.test.app` how would i do this?

Comment: `bash` or `sh`? The solutions for each, here, is entirely different.

Comment: Also, I fixed the syntax -- `foo = bar`, with the spaces, is not a valid shell assignment (it runs `foo` as a command with `=` as its first argument).

Comment: (also, `echo $packageinfo` actually behaves in some unwanted and surprising ways; be in the habit of using `echo "$packageinfo"` instead -- see #14 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls for details).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming bash, not POSIX sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ IMPORTANT, not /bin/sh

re="name='([^']*)'"
if [[ $packageinfo =~ $re ]]; then
  echo "name is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

That said, there are certainly POSIX sh solutions available as well. To pick one that doesn't require external tools such as `awk` or `sed`:

```
#!/bin/sh

getval() {
  target=$1; shift
  q="'"
  for arg; do
    case $arg in
      *=*)
        k=${arg%%=*}
        v=${arg#*=}; v=${v#$q}; v=${v%$q}
        if [ "$k" = "$target" ]; then
          printf '%s\n' "$v"
          return 0
        fi
        ;;
    esac
  done
}

packageinfo="package: name='nl.test.app' versionCode='64' versionName='5.1' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2438415'"

set -f # disable globbing

# expand without quotes to break into words; only safe with globbing disabled
getval name $packageinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement Charles Duffy's helpful [pure Bash/shell solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094974/45375) with a POSIX-compliant `awk` solution, assuming that - as is common - tagging a question with `bash` or `shell` simply means that a solution that can be *called* from the shell is desired, so that using standard Unix utilities *is* an option:

```
packageinfo="package: name='nl.test.app' versionCode='64' versionName='5.1' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2438415'"

packagename=$(echo "$packageinfo" | awk -F".* name='|'" '{ print $2 }')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the POSIX `expr` command:

```
name=$(expr "$packageinfo" : ".*name='\([^']*\)'")
```